# Probability of finding 1 ball in N boxes choosing randomly n boxes

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving

Let’s say there’s 1 ball hidden in N boxes. You can open $n<N$ boxes. What’s the probability of finding the ball?

My approach: the way of choosing $n$ from $N$ boxes
$$ \binom{N}{n}$$
Choosing the one that has the ball there are $N-1$ boxes left and $n-1$ to pick so
$$\binom{N-1}{n-1}$$
ways to do it.
Then the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{N-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}}=\frac{n}{N}$$
Probability is not my forte. I think I’m wrong… am I?

Edit: I wasn't wrong thanks to all, but the logic would be the same if there were $k<n$ balls hidden? (one ball per box only)

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong ?

Comment: Well. you can simply conceive that the probability is $n/N$. The simpler the ideation for a problem, the less chances of getting comfused or err.

Comment: Um, what? @trueblueanil

Comment: There are simpler arguments, but this works. This is the same as labeling the boxes from $1$ to $N$ and asking what is the probability, if you pick a random box, that it's label with be $\leq n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Am i wrong, or just comfused ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe because of the simple answer hahah. It's like $n$ balls where distributed in $N$ boxes and you have to pick one. I thought it would be less probable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why are they the same? I mean, why this problem, your problem and the problem i gave to TheSilverDoe are analogous?

Comment: You were wrong to think that you were wrong.

Comment: All of the problems are equivalent to you buying $n$ tickets and somebody else buying $N-n$ tickets in a lottery with a single prize.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more interesting heheh

Comment: @trueblueanil "The simpler the ideation..." is not meaningful. I have no idea what you are saying, and I'm American, so I almost speak English. Quite a few people posting here read English as a second language. What are you saying?

Comment: @RubénTobar with your final line edit, you have a hypergeometric distribution for the number you find, with expectation $k\frac nN$

Comment: Rephrase the game as two people, $A$ who places the ball, and $B$ who chooses the $n$ boxes. If $B$ chooses the boxes  before $A$ places the ball, but does not reveal the choices to $A$ until after the ball is placed, does that change the probability?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: "Ideation" is not such a complex word, looking up the first two results, I get "**the formation of ideas or concepts.**"[Oxford Languages], "**the activity of forming ideas in the mind**"[Cambridge]

Comment: Yes, and I know what the word means, but I don't know what you are saying about the OPs question. (I actually looked up the word, because I thought it might mean something else, because I didn't understand what you were getting at with the word. Then I wondered if it was an autocorrect for something else.) @trueblueanil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right. There's a couple ways of thinking about it; the comments on your post talk about a simple equivalent problem (think about why there's a bijection between the 2 ways of counting!).

You could even just brute force it. Either you find it on the first try, the second try, ..., the nth try. This probability comes to

$\frac{1}{N} + \frac{N-1}{N} \cdot \frac{1}{N-1} + \frac{N-1}{N} \cdot \frac{N-2}{N-1} \cdot \frac{1}{N-2} + ... + \frac{N-1}{N} \cdot \frac{N-2}{N-1} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{N-(n-1)}{N-(n-2)} \cdot \frac{1}{N-(n-1)}$

and that's equal to $\frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{N} + ... + \frac{1}{N} = \frac{n}{N}.$

Your original answer also works well and is quite elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Since questions were raised over the comment I made, and you also tried to gauge my intention of how to directly arrive at an answer, I feel I should clarify.

Your answer is fine, and the method you have used is very useful, specially  for more difficult questions.

The model I would have used here is that I have $n$ tickets in a lottery with $N$ total tickets, and only $1$ prize.

Then, without further thought, I could write $Pr = \large\frac{n}{N}$